# My VCALENDAR boundary won't work

Tags: outlook, gmail, boundary, vcalendar, vcal

I'm having an issue around adding a VCalendar to my email using boundaries.
I'm not getting an error in gmail, it just doesn't show that the message contains an event.
This is the email source:

> Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>       boundary="b1_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2"
>
> --b1_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>       boundary="b2_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2"
>
> --b2_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> This is to advise that your booking on the following course has been
>   cancelled:
>
> --b2_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> This is to advise that your booking on the following course has been cancelled:
>
> --b2_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2--
>   Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>   PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
>   VERSION:2.0
>   METHOD:REQUEST
>   BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
>   TZID:Eastern Time
>   BEGIN:STANDARD
>   DTSTART:20091101T020000
>   RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
>   TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
>   TZOFFSETTO:-0500
>   TZNAME:EST
>   END:STANDARD
>   BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
>   DTSTART:20090301T020000
>   RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
>   TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
>   TZOFFSETTO:-0400
>   TZNAME:EDST
>   END:DAYLIGHT
>   END:VTIMEZONE
>   BEGIN:VEVENT
>   ORGANIZER;CN="webmaster":MAILTO:webmaster@example.com
>   ATTENDEE;CN="Joseph";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:test@email.com
>   LAST-MODIFIED:20150323T95540
>   UID:20151112T1800002068512894@exchangecore.com
>   DTSTAMP:20150323T95540
>   DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":20151112T180000
>   DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":20151112T190000
>   TRANSP:OPAQUE
>   SEQUENCE:1
>   SUMMARY:My Test Subject
>   LOCATION:Joe's House
>   CLASS:PUBLIC
>   PRIORITY:5
>   BEGIN:VALARM
>   TRIGGER:-PT15M
>   ACTION:DISPLAY
>   DESCRIPTION:Reminder
>   END:VALARM
>   END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR
>
> --b1_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2--

I seems like I'm getting the boundaries wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what the issue was. The boundary I put before the VCALENDAR:

> --b2_83e86bab65095a2eb1fc16096e160ba2--

was the closing boundary. Changed it to this and it worked:

> --b2_4c2e4ee4b47bcb7c7521ef7d785e2701
>   Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST; charset="UTF-8"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>   [VLAC DETAILS]
>   END:VCALENDAR
>
> --b2_4c2e4ee4b47bcb7c7521ef7d785e2701--
>
> --b1_4c2e4ee4b47bcb7c7521ef7d785e2701--